# Difference between "nella scatola" and "in scatola"

Tags: difference, prepositions, articles

In the following sentence:

> Le scarpe sono ancora in/nella scatola.

Is there any difference in meaning/usage between "in scatola" and "nella scatola"?

Comment: I think it's something similar to [this](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/11233/is-in-or-nella-more-usual-in-this-context).

Comment: I'm not sure about the grammar behind this, but to my ear "in scatola" sounds idiomatic only for canned food (*carne in scatola*) and board games (*giochi in scatola*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I noted in a comment, to my ear "in scatola" sounds idiomatic only for canned food (*carne in scatola*) and board games (*giochi in scatola*).

I think the general rule behind this is that the *preposizione semplice* is used for general or idiomatic meanings / set expressions, while the *preposizione articolata* is used for referring to a specific object.

The same idea appears in English, too: *go to church* vs *go to/into the church*. So you would use *in scatola* when you use *boxed* in English, and *nella scatola* when you use *in their box* in English. In one case it's the general concept of something that comes in a box, in the other you are speaking about a specific box that you can point your finger at.

See for instance item two on [this grammar text](https://learnamo.com/preposizioni-articolate/).

Comment: It seems to me that the general rule you described does not apply to this context, as "to be in the box" here has a general meaning of "being in the (unspecified) box in which it was sold", but "in scatola" is not usual in this context. Is that right?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista That sounds about right. I can confirm that "in scatola" and "nella scatola" convey those meanings to me in that sentence (one is "boxed" and one is "in their box"), but I don't have a good answer on why "nella scatola" is more common/idiomatic than "in scatola" here.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: It's the opposite of an "unspecified" box: it's their very own box, the one the shoes came in, as opposed to food or games that is canned/boxed rather than sold by weight etc.

Comment: @DaG I am unable to see how the container of some food and the container of a pair of shoes differ in this aspect. A can of beans is also their very own can, the one the beans came in. Same for a game box. The choice between "in" and "nella" seems arbitrary to me here.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. The difference is not between shoes and beans, but among _these_ shoes (your sentence says “_le_ scarpe”, so a precise pair of shoes we are talking about), and beans as a kind of food. You'd say “i fagioli sono nel barattolo” as well, if we were talking about a particular portion of beans.

Comment: Infatti, l'uso idiomatico dell'espressione "in scatola" con valore aggettivale viene riportato sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI17/00897.jpg) in cui si menzionano anche accezioni di uso figurato (non appare, però, "gioco in scatola").